# iOS Realm detect changes for RLMObject

Tags: ios, realm

I have written code like this to listen for changes in Post object.

```
    notification = Post.allObjects(in: RLMRealm.encryptedRealm()! as! RLMRealm).addNotificationBlock({ (results, changes, error) in
        let pred = NSPredicate(format:  "tag == %@", self.postTag)
        self.posts = CommonResult.objects(with: pred).sortedResults(usingKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)

        if let _ = changes {
            if (changes!.insertions.count > 0 || changes!.deletions.count > 0 || changes!.modifications.count > 0) {
                    self.tblListing.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

In my Post object, there are 2 property. One is 'rowHeight' and another is 'isLikeByMyself'.

I want to reload tableview only if 'isLikeByMyself' is changed. How shall I do? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options.

If you don't have many `Post` objects, you may want to consider registering [object notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications) on each of them. Object notifications tell you which properties were changed and how, so you can use that information to reload the table view. However, you will need to register a separate notification on each `Post` object, which may not be practical if you have a large number of them.

Here is an alternate idea. Add an [ignored](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#ignoring-properties) boolean property to `Post` called something like `isLikeWasChanged`, and add a Swift `didSet` block that will set `isLikeWasChanged` to `true` any time you modify `isLikeByMyself`. Then, in your existing collection observation block, reload the table view only if at least one `isLikeWasChanged` is `true`, remembering to set them all back to `false` before you leave the block.